# How to stop Apollo-Server

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo-server

I am starting apollo-server with unittests and would like to gracefully stop the server, but in unit tests I get `Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::4000 (and Mocha's done() called multiple times)`

Here the start and stop functions:

```
let apollo_server = null;

exports.start = function(options, callback) {
  options.schema = schema
  options.formatError = (error) => {
    console.log('Fail to start graphql server', error);
    return error;
  }
  apollo_server = new ApolloServer(options);
  apollo_server.listen().then(({ url, subscriptionsUrl }) => {
    console.log('Grapql server started.', url, subscriptionsUrl);
  });
  callback();
}

exports.stop = function(callback) {
  apollo_server.stop().then(()=>{
     console.log("server stopped")l
     callback();
     })
}
```

Testing is done with Apollo-link, apollo-links-ws and subscriptions-transport-ws. It starts with following config to access graphql server>

```
const serverConfig = { serverUrl: 'http://localhost:4000/', subscriptionUrl: 'ws://localhost:4000/graphql' };
```

The test looks like following:

```
describe('Start query', function() {

  before('Start the graphql server', function(callback) {
    const options = { playground: false };
    graphql_server.start(options, callback);
  });


  before('Create owner', function(callback) {
    datasource.new_owner({ name: "test1" })
    callback()
  });

  it('Should return created entry of a query', (callback) => {
    owner_query.variables = { id: '4711' }
    execute(link, owner_query).subscribe({
      next: ({ data }) => {
        expect(data.owners.length).to.be.equal(1)
        callback()
      },
      error: error => { expect(error).to.be.null },
      complete: () => {},
    });
  })

  after('Stop server', function(callback) {
    graphql_server.stop((data) => {
      console.log("stop1", data)
      callback()
    })
  })
})
```

This is the second test. The first is similar for a mutation and is does not throw an error. The second test case ends with error on listen EADDRINUSE of port 4000.

What do I miss?

Comment: Please show how these functions are actually being used inside your test.

Comment: I added in the question the test details.

Comment: Could be the subscription server from 'subscriptions-transport-ws' which is included in the apollo-server??